# Idea Production Function References

Tags: reference-request, economic-growth, production-function, technological-progress

I've read in growth theory about the Idea production function:
$\dot{A}=f(A,S)$
which states that the change in ideas or blueprints or patents is a function of past ideas and the number of scientists.
The literature is dominated by Jones and was also recently discussed in Bloom et al (2020) Are Ideas getting harder to find?, AER.

Does anyone know of papers that are critical to this approach?

Comment: Critical *to* this approach or critical *of* this approach?

Comment: I guess critical of this approach is the more familiar wording.